# why is file pointer null?

Tags: c

In the following program, file_ptr is NULL, yet it is being initialized properly. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void Fopen(const char * restrict filePath, const char * restrict mode, FILE * restrict filePtr);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE * file_ptr = NULL;
    Fopen("dummy.dat", "r", file_ptr);
    printf("File pointer is %p\n", file_ptr);

    exit(0);
}

void Fopen(const char * restrict filePath, const char * restrict mode, FILE * restrict filePtr)
{
    if ( (filePtr = fopen(filePath, mode)) != NULL)
            printf("file pointer is %p\n", filePtr);
}
```

On Command Line:

```
[jim@cola c++]$ ./readFile
file pointer is 0x740010
File pointer is (nil)
```

The only explanation is that a copy of FILE * is being passed to Fopen. How can i pass pointer by ref?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Fopen` function changes the value of its local `filePtr` and then throws that value away. Nothing in your code can change the value of `file_ptr` in the caller. You just pass a NULL to the function.

You want this:

```
FILE* Fopen(const char * restrict filePath, const char * restrict mode)
{
    FILE* filePtr;
    if ( (filePtr = fopen(filePath, mode)) != NULL)
            printf("file pointer is %p\n", filePtr);
    return filePtr;
}
```

Comment: You can't in C, but you can pass a pointer to the pointer. Make the function take a `FILE **` and pass it `&file_ptr`.

Comment: So, there is no way to pass by ref in c?

Comment: C only supports passing by value. You can pass a pointer by value though, which gives you the same effect as passing by reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
void Fopen(const char * restrict filePath, const char * restrict mode, FILE * restrict filePtr)
```

You are passing pointer to FILE in the 3rd argument, and you change THE POINTER in the function. You can't do that dude. You must pass the address of this pointer instead. So it will look like (don't forget to change the body as well):

```
void Fopen(const char * restrict filePath, const char * restrict mode, FILE ** restrict filePtr)
```

and call with:

```
Fopen("dummy.dat", "r", &file_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C function arguments are passed by value.

```
FILE * file_ptr = NULL;
Fopen("dummy.dat", "r", file_ptr);
```

You only pass the value of `file_ptr` to `Fopen`. To modify `file_ptr` object you have to pass a pointer to it. This means `Fopen` function would have a `FILE **` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use c++, you can write

`const char * restrict filePath` as

`const char * & filePath`

PS: keyword **restrict** doesn't work in c++